# Basics of macro implementation - missing components

Tags: gimp, automation, script

I am going through [GIMP manual](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Automate_Editing_in_GIMP) and stuck for my shame at the beginning. How do I call that autoCommander? Is it example for the final result?

[image]

And assume I wrote that pseudo code into `~/.gimp-2.8/myXml/commander/NormalGridCanvas.def`:

```
commander>Normal Grid and Canvas
   macro>
      comment>Shrink the Canvas back to fit the layer
      >>>theImage.resize_to_layers()
      comment>Set grid to origin and size = image
      >>>pdb.gimp_image_grid_set_offset(theImage, 0, 0)
      >>>pdb.gimp_image_grid_set_spacing(theImage, theImage.width, theImage.height)
```

To convert this to an XML I am supposed to use the `GenCommanderXml()` from `XmlGenerator()` class from `autoBase.py`. According to the next picture it can be called from the GUI:

[image]

But I don't have a menu item called "Automation". I also tried to call `GenCommanderXml` in a GIMP's Python Console but that failed as well. What do I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - this you are pointing too is not the oficial GIMP manual - it is on "tutorial" section - and the proposed tool there does not actually exist.

I don't know what it is doing in "tutorials" - it is a loose bunch of ideas on what would be possible to do using GIMP scripting - however, from the first third of that post and bellow it is just a lot of whishful thinking of the author - only the very first listing there is something concrete (Example - GIMP-Python Code Fragment)  and still rather useless - it puts lots of extense calls just to set a single image grid options.

What is possible is to script GIMP in Python language - for which we lack good documentation or tutorials. The official docs are here: http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/  - but they lack examples of immediate use (in contrast with writing a full plug-in) . If you look my GIMP related answers here and on Stack Overflow you will see a lot of other examples.

Comment: Then I maybe should ask a question about my case to provide you an opportunity giving another answer with a good example :)

Comment: definitely. Feel free to e-mail me a link to the question (see profile for contact details)

Comment: Is it ok if I just ask a question like "How do I ... in GIMP?" Because I don't have anything to show "What I've already tried" till now. I just have a requirement what I want to get as result.

Comment: It is, just be sure that the result you want to achieve is clear.